# Why is storing a user identifier in an HTTP request header field considered stateless but storing it in a URI is not?

Tags: rest, http, uri, basic-authentication, stateless

A user identifier should never be stored in a URI. This is to enforce the REST stateless constraint (no server-side application state) according to Roy Fielding, [§ 6.2.5 ‘REST Mismatches in URI’](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2_5) of his doctoral dissertation *Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-Based Software Architectures*:

> Although the URI design matches REST's architectural notion of
> identifiers, syntax alone is insufficient to force naming authorities
> to define their own URI according to the resource model. **One form of
> abuse is to include information that identifies the current user
> within all of the URI referenced by a hypermedia response
> representation.** Such embedded user-ids can be used to maintain session
> state on the server, track user behavior by logging their actions, or
> carry user preferences across multiple actions (e.g., Hyper-G's
> gateways [84]). However, by violating REST's constraints, these
> systems also cause shared caching to become ineffective, reduce server
> scalability, and result in undesirable effects when a user shares
> those references with others.

And HTTP/1.1 basic authentication abides by the REST stateless constraint, according to Roy Fielding, [§ 5.1.2 ‘Considerations for New Authentication Schemes’](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-5.1.2) of his RFC 7235:

> **HTTP authentication is presumed to be stateless: all of the
> information necessary to authenticate a request MUST be provided in
> the request, rather than be dependent on the server remembering prior
> requests.**  Authentication based on, or bound to, the underlying
> connection is outside the scope of this specification and inherently
> flawed unless steps are taken to ensure that the connection cannot be
> used by any party other than the authenticated user (see Section 2.3
> of [RFC7230]).

Yet HTTP/1.1 allows the storage of a user identifier in the request header field `Authorization` to authenticate the user agent with an origin server, according to Roy Fielding, [§ 2.1 ‘Challenge and Response’](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-2.1) of his RFC 7235:

> A user agent that wishes to authenticate itself with an origin server
> -- usually, but not necessarily, after receiving a 401 (Unauthorized)
> -- can do so **by including an Authorization header field with the request.**

So why is storing a user identifier in an HTTP request header field considered stateless but storing it in a URI is not?

It appears to me that transmitting a user identifier, regardless of the channel (URI, header field, body), identifies a user agent with the origin server and therefore allows storing server-side application state for that user agent. In other words, to me authentication is actually the means to achieve *stateful* communication.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to review Fielding's description of 5.1.3 ([Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)):

> each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.

That's the key idea for "Stateless" - you should be able to understand the semantics of each and every request in isolation from all others.

---

> So why is storing a user identifier in an HTTP request header field considered stateless but storing it in a URI is not?

It's not.  Both mechanisms are stateless (as Fielding defines it in the context of REST).

The violation described by Fielding in 6.2.5 is *not* a violation of 5.1.3, but is instead better understood as a violation of 5.1.4 ([Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)) and 5.1.5 ([Uniform Interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)).

Put another way: storing session state on the server is bad (it violates 5.1.3, and therefore compromises some of your scaling); what doesn't matter is whether you access that cached session state using information in a Cookie header, information in an Authentication header, or information in the URI.

But encoding session state key into your resource identifiers *also* jacks with your caching, and your ability to use a resource identifier as a proxy for the representation of the resource.

Comment: Now, what is the point of HTTP authentication if it is not accessing application state stored on the server, thereby violating the stateless constraint? I am asking this because I have always believed that user-specific state = application state, and shared state = resource state.

Comment: The point of authentication is access control - it's a standardized mechanism for determining the authority of the request.  It doesn't violate the stateless constraint because every authorized request carries its own authorization credentials (the server doesn't have to "remember" information from any prior requests.

Comment: Okay, in other words, the point of authentication is authorization (to access a resource). So you are saying that it is never to access user-specific data, otherwise it violates the stateless constraint. Thus all websites that store user-specific data like preferences (e.g. GitHub, Stack Overflow), payment information or delivery information (e.g. Amazon, Uber Eats) are not RESTful?

Comment: No, that's not a correct interpretation of what I am saying.  It's perfectly fine to have resources whose representations include user information.  Resource state (meaning the current expression of the temporally varying membership function) and session state (the context of the interactions between the client and server) are _different_ things.

Comment: I see. So authentication can also be used to access user-specific data (so not only for access control), which does not imply that these user-specific data are application state. User-specific data can be resource state too. My assumption *application state* (a.k.a. *session state*) = user-specific state, and *resource state* = shared state was false.

Comment: Roy Fielding said in a comment on his blog article [*REST APIs must be hypertext-driven*](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven): ‘Don’t confuse application state (the state of the user’s application of computing to a given task) with resource state (the state of the world as exposed by a given service). They are not the same thing.’ I find the difference between the two hard to grasp. I might need a few examples. As I now understand it, application state is the progress of a task (e.g. 35%) and resource state is a form with a fixed meaning (e.g. a person).

Comment: "Think about it until you do, it's an important concept".  Study that question in the context of the web - what does the _browser_ know about vs what does the _server_ know about?  In the Fielding dissertation, review 5.3.3, 3.4.6, 3.4.7.

Comment: You are right, resource state/application state are really important concepts. I have reviewed the recommended sections. I need to think about them more tonight. By the way, could you explain why including the user-id in a URI violate the cache constraint and the identification of resources constraint?

Comment: Since the cache constraint only requires that responses be implicitly or explicitly labeled as cacheable or non-cacheable by the client or the server, I don’t see how that constraint is violated by including a user identifier in the URI. Fielding does not say that it violates the cache constraint but prevents *shared* caching: ‘by violating REST's constraints, these systems also cause shared caching to become ineffective’.

Comment: And I don’t understand his argument on shared caching by the way, since even including the user identifier in the `Authorization` header field prevents shared caching and only allows *private* caching (cf. [§ 5.1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-5.1.2) of RFC 7235): ‘The credentials carried in an Authorization header field are specific to the user agent and, therefore, have the same effect on HTTP caches as the "private" Cache-Control response directive’

Comment: So for the moment I can only agree with the violation of the identification of resources constraint of the uniform interface, since Fielding mentions it almost explicitly: ‘is insufficient to force naming authorities to define their own URI according to the resource model’.